# Hibernate: How can I set a range for a number or a minimum or a maximum for a number?

Tags: hibernate, range

I found some examples using @Range and @DecimalMin but I can't seem to make'em working.

In fact, what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

These annotations are part of [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) project, which is an implementation of JSR-303 bean validation API.

For integration with Hibernate see [6.3. ORM integration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-checkconstraints.html#validator-checkconstraints-orm).